# Asp.net - Javascript does not work on an iframe containing MVC view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, qlikview

I've created a view to display a "qlikview" document inside an iframe. Iframe prevents any javascript execution when the mentioned view called from a controller. If I remove the iframe js works fine.

Iframe works ok but js not. What would be the reason of this?

Thanks.

My View:

```html
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <iframe id="qlikFrame" src="@ViewBag.IframeLink" style="width:100%; height:768px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
</div>
```

_Layout:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   alert("you clicked the paragraph");
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          @if (@Request.IsAuthenticated) {
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="dropdown-item" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dashboards
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("SD", "Document", "Dashboard", new { Id = SD" }, null)</li>
              } @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("RolesAdmin", "Index", "RolesAdmin")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("UsersAdmin", "Index", "UsersAdmin")</li>
              }
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
  </div>

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of a strange behaviour of vs2015 or MVC, not sure which one.

The problem is about iframe closure tag:

if I write `<iframe></iframe>` Js works, but if I write `<iframe />` Js doesn't work.

In a webform project in vwd2010, I've used the latter syntax, iframe and Js worked without any problem.
If anyone meets this misbehaviour, above might be the resolution.